# Squarespace: Overriding a global class attribute with an ID

Tags: css, squarespace

I have a Squarespace website with many pages of Summary Block Galleries, each containing both images and text. These galleries have an annoying default lightbox feature with a hover state that displays unformatted text over the image.

I want to cancel this lightbox behavior for all the galleries except one. My first thought was to globally cancel all Summary Block Gallery lightboxes like this:

```
  .summary-thumbnail-container {
  pointer-events: none;
  }
```

Then for the single Summary Block Gallery instance I want to remain clickable, I would simply target its collection ID:

```
  #collection-538. . .15bb .summary-thumbnail-container {
  pointer-events: auto; 
  }
```

The lightboxes are successfully cancelled globally, but the ID targeting doesn't work to override the effect on the single instance.

What have I missed? Thanks.

Comment: Shoudn't this 
"#collection-538. . .15bb .summary-thumbnail-container"
be "#collection-538 .summary-thumbnail-container"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some random characters in your selector. Try this:

```
#collection-538 .summary-thumbnail-container {
    pointer-events: auto; 
}
```

Comment: The random characters are probably intentional. I suspect Squarespace automatically generates random hexadecimal numbers for its ids.

Answer (score 0):

For this you'll want to use a Block ID instead. If you look into the markup you'll see Squarespace has a `#blockid-123....789` along side of the `.sqs-block` classes that allows you to target by block instead of collection. Targeting a collection ID is going to disable the clicks for all galleries on the page.

Also, I would consider using a CSS not() pseudo-class as specified here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not.

Comment: I like the idea of using the pseudo-class, but there’s something more fundamental I’m not understanding. I’ve created a test page with two Summary Gallery List blocks, each with images, titles and body text. Each block has a unique Collection ID and Block ID. Using a code block on the page, I can’t seem to target the Summary Block using its Block ID:

    `<style>#block-0d2d0a4e8cc4b836a97a .sqs-block .summary-v2- block .sqs-block-summary-v2 {
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
</style>`

Answer (score 0):

Happy to report that my original plan was valid, but just poorly executed. First, I disabled all light boxes globally for both Summary Gallery Block images AND title links in the Custom CSS window:

```
    .summary-thumbnail-container, .summary-title-link {
pointer-events: none;
 }
```

My original mistake was failing to separate classes with a comma. Some had recommended using the !important qualifier here, but it doesn’t seem to be necessary.

Finally, using a Code Block on a single web page, I was able to target a Summary Gallery Block on that page using a collectionId to return the pointer-events to their default setting:

```
    <style>#collection-5785e43e15d5dbb0fab6719c 
.sqs-block-summary-v2, .summary-thumbnail-container {
 pointer-events: auto !important;
 }
  </style>
```

I still like Jason Barone’s recommendation for using the CSS not() pseudo-class, but that will have to be my next project.